# Is there a reliable way to count the number of digits after the decimal point for a float in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

I'd like to be able to find a ***reliable*** way to count the number of valid digits after the decimal point for a float value that is passed into a function in Erlang. Say the name of the desired function is `counter`, and it should behave like this:

```
counter(3.14) => 2
counter(3.00001) => 5
counter(3.10000) => 1
```

Thank you, everybody.

---

Update: due to the nature of the representation of floating point numbers, this problem is highly unlikely to be solvable.

Comment: Hi Ning, be aware that the floating point representation is not unique (I don't know how to express it better) for example on my machine, `1.79999999999999997 =:= 1.80000` is true

Comment: Hi Ning, after reading your question I have been looking for other way to represent numbers and floats. I found some interesting thing with the continued fraction. As an exercise I tried to apply to the evaluation of pi, this fraction gives more than 100 digit :O)  `4170888101980193551139105407396069754167439670144501/1327634917026642108692848192776111345311909093498260`

Comment: This one gives exactly 100 digits (after the dot) `394372834342725903069943709807632345074473102456264/125532772013612015195543173729505082616186012726141` equals `3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679...`

Comment: and here are the first 10 best approximations of pi (ordered by increasing denominator): `[{3,1},
 {22,7},
 {333,106},
 {355,113},
 {103993,33102},
 {104348,33215},
 {208341,66317},
 {312689,99532},
 {833719,265381},
 {1146408,364913}]
`

Answer (score 2):

There is definitively no reliable way to do this.  Floats are base 2 numbers.  You're asking a question about a finite-length base-10 representation of them.  For most decimals, no exact base 2 float representation exists.  We could make guesses, like the system does when it formats them as string or for output.  But provably, none of them are always correct.

Comment: This is the reason I don't like floats:( I am trying to represent all numbers in a system in terms of fractions like {314, 100} for 3.14. Thanks for clearing up for me, mate:)

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo-code,

- Convert to the desired string representation.
- Check for decimal point? absent, return 0
- Trim rightmost zeroes to right of decimal point.
- Count remaining characters right of decimal point

Comment: There isn't a reliable way to `Convert to the desired string representation`:( The only way seems to work for me is to make sure that all the floats created outside of the system should be entered into the system in string form.